# My Django form is not valid

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I'm having problems with a Django form. I cant find the error and how I can fix it.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin,
BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django import forms

class Person(models.Model):
person_userid=models.ForeignKey(User)
person_availability_choices=(
    ('M', 'Monday'),
    ('T', 'Tuesday'),
    ('W', 'Wednesday'),
    ('Th', 'Thursday'),
    ('F', 'Friday'),
    ('Sat', 'Saturday'),
    ('Sun', 'Sunday'),
)
person_availability=models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=person_availability_choices)
person_salutation_choices=(
    ('Mr.', 'Mr.'),
    ('Mrs.', 'Mrs.'),
    ('Ms.', 'Ms.'),
    ('Dr.', 'Dr.'),
)
person_salutation=models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=person_salutation_choices)
person_first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_date_of_birth=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
person_address_street=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_address_suite=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
person_address_city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_address_state=models.CharField(max_length=2)
person_address_zip=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
person_address_county=models.CharField(max_length=25)
person_live_within_bloom=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
person_home_phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
person_cell_phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
person_work_phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
person_email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_second_email=models.CharField(max_length=50)
person_communication_preference_choices=(
    ('Phone','Phone'), 
    ('Email', 'Email'), 
    ('Text', 'Text'),
)
person_communication_preference=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=person_communication_preference_choices)
person_dob=models.DateField()
person_entered_in_donor_database=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
person_community_member=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
person_participation_start_date=models.DateField()
person_participation_end_date=models.DateField()
person_reason_for_leaving_choices=(
    ('Moving', 'Moving'), 
    ('Financial', 'Financial'), 
    ('Medical', 'Medical'), 
    ('Graduated', 'Graduated'), 
    ('CSH', 'Completed Service Hours'), 
    ('Other', 'Other'),
)
person_reason_for_leaving=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=person_reason_for_leaving_choices)
person_note=models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Volunteer(Person):
volunteer_types=(
    ('Program', 'Program'),
    ('Admin', 'Admin'),
    ('Committee', 'Committee'),
)
person_volunteer_type=models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=volunteer_types)

volunteer_allergies=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_medications=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_health_notes=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
volunteer_high_school_grad_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) # replace null = True.... with name as done for date_of_birth
volunteer_college_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
volunteer_college_grad_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
volunteer_orientation_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
leader_training1_start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
leader_training1_end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
leader_training2_start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
leader_training2_end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
stable_manager_training_start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
stable_manager_training_end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
volunteer_community_member=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_board_member=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_board_member_start_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
volunteer_board_member_end_date=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
volunteer_horse_experience=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_horse_experience_details=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_experience_with_disabilities=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_experience_with_disabilities_details=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_computer_skills_details=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_facility_maintenance_experience_details=models.CharField(max_length=100)
volunteer_construction=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_lift_fifty_lbs=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_language_proficiency=models.CharField(max_length=50)
volunteer_CPR_trained=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_landscaping=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_skill_fundraising=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_skill_PR=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=yes_no)
volunteer_skills_other=models.CharField(max_length=500)
volunteer_of_month_recognition=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
volunteer_of_year_recognition=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
#volunteer_personid=models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

views.py

```
def volunteer_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VolunteerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> alert("You have sucessful created a new Volunteer"); location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/volunteer_form/" </script>')
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        detail_id = request.GET['id']
        query_results = User.objects.filter(id = detail_id)
        form = VolunteerForm()  
        return render(request, 'loginPortal/volunteer_form.html', {'form' : form, 'query_results' : query_results})
```

forms.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from loginPortal.models import Volunteer, Client

class VolunteerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Volunteer

class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
```

So I'm getting the error that the form is not validated. and I cant find the error. If any one can help me with this, I will be glad

Answer (score 1):

It forms.py, you're referencing:

```
model = Client
```

...after doing an import above. You don't have a model called 'Client' in models.py, you have a model called 'Person'.

Comment: No, sorry but I do have the model Client, But I didn't post all my model file. The form and model client is similiar to Volunteer, but I'm doing nothing with that now, the problem is with my volunteer and the program keep saying the form is no valid.

Comment: The proper error is that I don't have a HttpResponse, however it appear because it don't pass on the "is_valid" test. I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of your view should look like this:

```
else:
    form = VolunteerForm()  
detail_id = request.GET['id']
query_results = User.objects.filter(id = detail_id)
return render(request, 'loginPortal/volunteer_form.html', {'form' : form, 'query_results' : query_results})
```

Only the `form` definition should be inside `else`, all the rest should be outside that block.

Comment: I see your point, however, this else isn't the problem here I'm using it to load a empty form with data of a previous one,and when I load the form for the first time, I don't have any problem. My problem only occurs when I'm trying to save the data. I dont have any problem to load the form.

Comment: Because the form is not valid, and your code does not return a response in that case. This code fixes that problem, so you display the errors back to the user.

Comment: Doesn't work. Because my form don't pass the "GET id".

Comment: Why are you passing the id as a GET parameter anyway, instead of as part of the URL?

Comment: I'm creating a new user using a different form, than I pass the user ID to this form by get. So I can refer the user Id with the volunteer form. So when I load the volunteer form for the 1st time I have the ID, that is the "else" case on the views code. Than when i fill up the Volunteer form, and send it by POST, I receive the error that my form isn't valid.

Comment: But don't pass an ID in the GET params, is my point. Construct a URL like you normally would in Django, ie `/volunteer/<user_id>/`.

Comment: This is my first time using Django, so I don't know how I can send this "id" by URL. 

This is a summer internship project, and I'm still learn how Django, if you have a better idea how I can pass the ID please help me. However, this will help me with the "validation" error? because I didn't have it first,  and I was getting the same error before.